# DAX to average values from another table using associations

Tags: powerbi, dax, ssas-tabular

Suppose I have these three tables in Power BI (a simplification from my enterprise app):

**Table_A**

| Coordinate | Value |
| --- | --- |
| A1 | 12 |
| A1 | 15 |
| A1 | 17 |
| A2 | 13 |
| A2 | 19 |

**Table_B**

| Coordinate | Value |
| --- | --- |
| B1 | 90 |
| B1 | 91 |
| B1 | 88 |
| B1 | 87 |
| B2 | 80 |
| B2 | 88 |
| B3 | 91 |
| B4 | 99 |
| B4 | 99 |
| B4 | 98 |
| B4 | 92 |

**Associations**

| Coordinate_A | Coordinate_B |
| --- | --- |
| A1 | B1 |
| A1 | B2 |
| A1 | B3 |
| A2 | B3 |
| A2 | B4 |

I'd like to use DAX to get an average of all B values associated with each A coordinate. So A1 has B1, B2 and B3 assocated with it (from the Associations table). So for A1, I'd like an average of all values with coordinates B1, B2, B3 from Table_B. For A2, I'd like an average of all B3 and B4 values from Table_B.

So the desired result in Power BI would look like this:

| Coordinate A | Average of A | Average of B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | 14.667 | 87.857 |
| A2 | 16 | 95.8 |

Can someone help with a DAX formula to give [Average of B] -- obviously grouped by [Coordinate A]? **NOTE: I'm using Direct Query against an SSAS tabular model in Power BI, and TREATAS (and some other functions) are not recognized.**

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the model looks like this with 2 inactive many-to-many relationships:
[image]

You could use this measure to get **Average of B**:

```
Average of B = 
CALCULATE (
    AVERAGE ( tbl2[Value] ),
    USERELATIONSHIP ( Assc[Coordinate_A], tbl1[Coordinate] ),
    USERELATIONSHIP ( Assc[Coordinate_B], tbl2[Coordinate] )
)
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: The model is in SSAS so this isn't going to work. SSAS doesn't handle many-to-many relationships, and you can't establish inactive relationships on top of those created in SSAS. Unless I'm missing something...